# Synchronize the scroll offset of a vertical split

Tags: key-bindings, split, scrolling

#### Set up

- Left (L) and right (R) are two vertically split windows displaying the same file.
- No other windows exist in the tab.
- The uppermost displayed line in L is x (`Lx`) and the uppermost line in R is y (`Ry`).
- The focused window is denoted by an asterisk (`*L` or `*R`).

#### Question

I am looking for a normal mode map to do this:

1. If L has focus: Change `*Lx Ry` into `*Lx Rx`.
2. If R has focus: Change `Lx *Ry` into `Ly *Ry`.

I.e., I want the offset between the windows to be zero.

#### Attempts

[`syncbind`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#:syncbind) almost solves the problem, but since it requires both windows
to have `scrollbind` set, and I rarely have it set, things get more complicated.
`windo` would apparently solve it:

```
noremap <F11> :windo set scb<bar>syncbind<CR>:windo set noscb<CR>
```

But although it works properly for case 2, it fails for case 1 because it shifts focus
to the right window.

Comment: The focus shift is probably from `windo`. You could save the current `winnr()` and use `execute winnr 'wincmd w'` or similar

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Indeed, I hadn't looked at `:h windo`: "The last window (or where an error occurred) becomes the current window". I will give it a try. I only wish we had a `syncbind!` to remove the offset of all windows regardless of `scrollbind`...

Answer (score 1):

```
noremap <expr> <F11> winnr()==1 ?
    \ ':windo set scb<CR><C-W><C-W>:syncbind<CR>:windo set noscb<CR><C-W><C-W>' :
    \ ':windo set scb<bar>syncbind<CR>:windo set noscb<CR>'
```

I have a strong feeling this solution exceedingly verbose and can probably be optimized, but it does the job.